# How to align columns so they are all in one row? HTML

Tags: html, image, text, flexbox, responsive

```
<div class="container" style="display: flex;  flex-direction: row; justify-content: left;  align-items: left; display:flex; margin: 10px; flex-wrap: wrap;">
```

[Image of Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXeDN.png)

In my HTML, I noticed if I remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` my columns become one row, however my webpage isn't responsive when I resize the browser window. When `flex-wrap: wrap;` is in there, it becomes 2 rows like in my image above, however it's responsive. Any ideas how I can make it one row and responsive at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the container, you can apply a `max-width` setting to the flex items (for example 25% to get four items into a row), and then use a media query for screens below a certain width with another max-width like 50% or (see example below) - and on smartphones, where you only want one item per row, 100%.

```
.flexcontainer > div {
   max-width: 25%;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flexcontainer > div {
    max-width: 50%;
  } 
}
```